Using 方が in a comparative clause
What about this sentence:

ジュリアのかみの方が僕のかみより長いです

How would you translate 方が?
As: Concerning... ?
and
Concerning Julia's hair, it is longer than mine.
as a translation for the whole sentence.
I would appreciate any reference concerning the use of 方が in similar comparative clauses.
Many thanks.

方 literally means 'side'. When you are comparing X with Y you have two sides i.e. the X side and the Y side.
Translating より is less clear cut. I like to translate it as 'when compared to'.
ジュリアのかみの方 (Julia's hair's side / the side which is Julia's hair)
僕のかみより (when compared to my hair)
長いです (is long)
i.e. Julia's hair is longer than my hair.

+1: I'm wondering if it would be of any help for learners to understand ＸよりＹの方 as "Y's direction seen from X."

Great. 1) is this structure the most commun to compare X'hair to Y'hair? 2) how would you build a comparative inferiority?

In addition to the full pattern, depending on previous context, either the 方 part or the より part can be omitted. Not sure what you mean by 'comparative inferiority'. If you wanted to say that Julia's hair was shorter then simply change 長い to 短い. If you have something else in mind it's probably worth a separate question.

Yes, I just wanted to say that: Julia's hair is shorter than mine (comparative inferioty). You have perfectly replied to my question.
